# Understanding fseek() in C

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread, fseek

I was learing File I/O in C and was interested in using it to read and write structures to files via `fwrite()` and `fread()` functions, now after my code ran successfully I was wondering if I could read a specific structure from an array of structures and put it in some given structure.

---

*Here is my attempt at it*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tools {
    int recordno;
    char toolname[50];
    int quantity;
    float cost;
} tools;

void recordprinter(tools a) {
    printf("%d %s %d %f\n", a.recordno, a.toolname, a.quantity, a.cost);
}

int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb+");
    tools * a = (tools * ) malloc(100 * sizeof(tools));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        a[i].cost = 0;
        a[i].toolname[0] = 'a';
        a[i].toolname[1] = '\0';
        a[i].quantity = 0;
        a[i].recordno = i + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fwrite(a + i, sizeof(tools), 1, fp);
        fseek(fp, sizeof(tools), SEEK_CUR);
        // I used fseek here just because fwrite doesnot move the cursor when\
        it writes something to the file.(and fwrite(a + i, sizeof(tools), 100, fp) gives weird gliches)
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // to bring cursor back to start of the file.

    fread(a, sizeof(tools), 1, fp);

    fseek(fp, sizeof(tools) * 50, SEEK_SET); // now I expect the cursor to be at 51th structure.

    fread(a + 3, sizeof(tools), 1, fp); // I am now writing the 51th structure in a[3]    

    recordprinter(a[3]);
    // this gives output 26 and not 51   

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I ran the programm I expected `51 a 0 0.00000` as output,
but to my surprise it is picking up the 26th structure and putting it in a[3]
Any help will be appritiated!!

Comment: `fwrite` should indeed move the "cursor", so two consecutive calls to `fwrite` to write to a file, should write to two different locations, one after the other. Same with `fread`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had the same feeling when I started with `fwrite`, but when you put `fwrite(a,sizeof(tools),100,fp) ` the programm often misbehaves so I avoid doing that

Comment: That's really how you should be doing it. What do you mean by "misbehaves"? Are you 100% sure it's not a problem in your program? Perhaps you should be asking a question about that "misbehavior" since it's really not something that should happen.

Comment: well I don't know why but its working when I change it to fwrite(a,sizeof(tools),100,fp)

Comment: With the loop doing `fseek` you create "holes" in your file, between each actual data you write. With the single `fwrite` call you write all the elements of the array consecutively into the file. Start by comparing the two files, for example using a hex-dump utility to see its contents.

Comment: `fwrite` moves the cursor, full stop.

Comment: C17 7.21.8.2/2 (describing the behavior of `fwrite`): "[...] The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully written. If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file position indicator for the stream is indeterminate." No "feelings" are involved.

Comment: However, you *do* need to interpose a file-positioning operation such as `fseek()` when switching from reading to writing the same stream.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So you mean if some error occurs while writting in the file then the cursor can be moved anwhere in the file by the compiler?(by the statement of your 1st commment)

Comment: @ChemicalBrewster, it's the spec saying it, not me.  "Indeterminate" is not quite the same thing as "anywhere in the file", but it does mean that you cannot rely on any particular value.  But note also that you don't have to wonder whether an error occurred.  You should be checking the return values of your function calls, and these will *tell you* when an error has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `fopen` to use `w+` instead of `rb+`

Also, remove the `fseek` when creating the file, as mentioned, `fwrite` definitely advances the file offset after writing data (provided `fwrite` does write data at all).

Here is the output observed using the modified code below.

```
gcc main.c
./a.out
51 a 0 0.000000
```

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tools {
    int recordno;
    char toolname[50];
    int quantity;
    float cost;
} tools;

void recordprinter(tools a) {
    printf("%d %s %d %f\n", a.recordno, a.toolname, a.quantity, a.cost);
}

int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    
    // recommend for this example using w+
    // w because it creates the file if the file doesn't exist
    // r fails if the file doesn't exist (and that doesn't seem useful here)
    // + because you are reading and writing
    // avoiding b and choosing POSIX - linux
    // may be wrong, if libc docs says b is needed then use b
    // my doc "man fopen" says b is ignored
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    // check return values, file pointer exist? fail if not
    if (fp==NULL) { printf( "oops file not opened\n" ); return 1; }
    tools * a = (tools * ) malloc(100 * sizeof(tools));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        a[i].cost = 0;
        a[i].toolname[0] = 'a';
        a[i].toolname[1] = '\0';
        a[i].quantity = 0;
        a[i].recordno = i + 1;
    }
    // alternative way to save 100 objects
    // if ( fwrite(a, sizeof(tools), 100, fp) != 100 )
    // {
    //   printf( "oops 100 objects not written to file\n" );
    //  return 1;
    // }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fwrite(a + i, sizeof(tools), 1, fp);
        // remove fseek, not needed, fwrite does what is needed here
        //fseek(fp, sizeof(tools), SEEK_CUR);
        // I used fseek here just because fwrite doesnot move the cursor when
        // it writes something to the file.(and fwrite(a + i, sizeof(tools), 100, fp) gives weird gliches)
    }

    // no review after this line, it seems to do what author intends

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // to bring cursor back to start of the file.

    fread(a, sizeof(tools), 1, fp);

    fseek(fp, sizeof(tools) * 50, SEEK_SET); // now I expect the cursor to be at 51th structure.

    fread(a + 3, sizeof(tools), 1, fp); // I am now writing the 51th structure in a[3]    

    recordprinter(a[3]);
    // this gives output 51 as desired   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some commentary on *why* you are recommending these changes would be in order.

Comment: Also, it seems inappropriate to open the file as a text file (`w+`).  Some implementations don't meaningfully distinguish between text and binary mode, but others do, and on those, applications using `fread()` and `fwrite()` generally require binary mode.  Maybe `wb+`, then.

Comment: `wb+` seems a good option and thankyou @atl

Comment: @JohnBollinger, agree - added some explanations on why I choose what is listed above

Comment: @atl, why choose an alternative that works only on *some* implementations when it's so easy to choose one that is more semantically correct and works on *all* implementations?